# PineScript from v3 to v4 - "is already defined" Reassignment problem

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert the script below from Pine Script Version 3 to Version 4. However, I receive an error, mentioning that the compilation is failed, lines 28:30: " obv " is already defined. I tried to add the reassignment operator (:=) on obv(src) before assigning a function (=>), but it didn't work. Does anybody have an idea of how this problem could be solved?

Thank you

```
//@version=3
//
// @author LazyBear
// 
// Appreciate a note if you use this code anywhere. 
// 
study(title="OBV with Divergence", shorttitle="OBV_Divergence_LB")

len = input(20)
src = close
lbR = input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=false)
plotBear = input(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=false)


bearColor = red
bullColor = green
hiddenBullColor = color(green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color(red, 80)
textColor = white
noneColor = color(white, 100)

obv(src) => cum(change(src) > 0 ? volume : change(src) < 0 ? -volume : 0*volume)
os=obv(src)
obv_osc = (os - ema(os,len))
obc_color=obv_osc > 0 ? green : red
plot(obv_osc, color=obc_color, style=line,title="OBV-Points", linewidth=2)
plot(obv_osc, color=silver, transp=70, title="OBV", style=area)
hline(0)

plFound = na(pivotlow(obv_osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(pivothigh(obv_osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish

// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = obv_osc[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bullCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bullish Label",
     text=" Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bullish

// Osc: Lower Low
oscLL = obv_osc[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low
priceHL = low[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(
     plFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBullCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bullish Label",
     text=" H Bull ",
     style=shape.labelup,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bullColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish

// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = obv_osc[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

plot(
     phFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     bearCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Regular Bearish Label",
     text=" Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bearish

// Osc: Higher High
oscHH = obv_osc[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High
priceLH = high[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(
     phFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish",
     linewidth=2,
     color=(hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor),
     transp=0
     )

plotshape(
     hiddenBearCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na,
     offset=-lbR,
     title="Hidden Bearish Label",
     text=" H Bear ",
     style=shape.labeldown,
     location=location.absolute,
     color=bearColor,
     textcolor=textColor,
     transp=0
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pine V4 have its own built-in function named obv(). So you have to rename `obv()` to, for example `obv_f()`, or delete this function and use built-in.

```
//@version=4
//
// @author LazyBear
// 
// Appreciate a note if you use this code anywhere. 
// 
study(title="OBV with Divergence", shorttitle="OBV_Divergence_LB")

len = input(20)
src = close
lbR = input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defval=60)
rangeLower = input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=false)
plotBear = input(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=false)


bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

obv_f(src) =>
    change_1 = change(src)
    cum(change(src) > 0 ? volume : change_1 < 0 ? -volume : 0 * volume)
os = obv_f(src)
obv_osc = os - ema(os, len)
obc_color = obv_osc > 0 ? color.green : color.red
plot(obv_osc, color=obc_color, style=plot.style_line, title="OBV-Points", linewidth=2)
plot(obv_osc, color=color.silver, transp=70, title="OBV", style=plot.style_area)
hline(0)

plFound = na(pivotlow(obv_osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(pivothigh(obv_osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bullish

// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = obv_osc[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(plFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bullish", linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(bullCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bullish Label", text=" Bull ", style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=bullColor, textcolor=textColor, transp=0)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bullish

// Osc: Lower Low
oscLL = obv_osc[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low
priceHL = low[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(plFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Hidden Bullish", linewidth=2, color=hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(hiddenBullCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Hidden Bullish Label", text=" H Bull ", style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=bullColor, textcolor=textColor, transp=0)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Regular Bearish

// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = obv_osc[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

plot(phFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bearish", linewidth=2, color=bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(bearCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Regular Bearish Label", text=" Bear ", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=bearColor, textcolor=textColor, transp=0)

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hidden Bearish

// Osc: Higher High
oscHH = obv_osc[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, obv_osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High
priceLH = high[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(phFound ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Hidden Bearish", linewidth=2, color=hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(hiddenBearCond ? obv_osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title="Hidden Bearish Label", text=" H Bear ", style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=bearColor, textcolor=textColor, transp=0)
```

Also it make sense to convert it to V5.

Comment: Thank you. I converted it from v5 to v4 using the Pine Script's automatic convert tool. It worked very well.